# How to swap sublists of two lists in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, list, sublist

I'm trying to swap two lists using only JavaScript but any approach I try seems to fail.

These are the two lists I have:

```
<h3>Lists</h3>
<ul >
    <li >l<sub>1  </sub>    
        <ul id="e1">
            <li>l<sub>11</sub>-a</li>
            <li>l<sub>12</sub>-b</li>
            <li>l<sub>13</sub>-a</li>
            <li>l<sub>14</sub>-a</li>
            <li>l<sub>15</sub>-b</li>
            <li>l<sub>16</sub>-b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li >l<sub>2  </sub>    
        <ul id="e2"> 
            <li>l<sub>21</sub>-b</li>
            <li>l<sub>22</sub>-a</li>
            <li>l<sub>23</sub>-a</li>
            <li>l<sub>24</sub>-b</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<br/>
```

So far, I've tried iterating through each list like so:

```
var temp, index;
var myFirstList  = document.getElementById("e1").getElementsByName("li");
var mySecondList = document.getElementById("e2").getElementsByName("li");

for (index = 0; index < myFirstList.length; index++)
{
    temp.appendChild(myFirstList.removeChild(myFirstList[0]);
}

for (index = 0; index < mySecondList.length; index++)
{
    myFirstList.appendChild(mySecondList.removeChild(mySecondList[0])); 
}

for (index = 0; index < temp.length; index++)
{
    mySecondList.appendChild(temp.removeChild(temp[0]));
}

document.getAttribute("e1").appendChild(myFirstList);
document.getAttribute("e2").appendChild(mySecondList);
```

I've also tried:

```
var myFirstList  = document.getElementById("e1").getElementsByName("li");
var mySecondList = document.getElementById("e2").getElementsByName("li");

document.getElementById("e1").removeAttribute(("li");
document.getElementById("e2").removeAttribute(("li");

document.getAttribute("e1").appendChild(myFirstList);
document.getAttribute("e2").appendChild(mySecondList);
```

Neither of these swapping the sublists in l1 and l2.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I did not understand what do you mean by swapping, please elaborate, however if you want to iterate over the li elements using their parent ul, you can do something like.

```
var sublist1 = document.getElementById('e1');
 for (var i=0; i<sublist1.children.length; i++){
      sublist1.children[i].innerHTML = someVariable;
 }
```

Comment: Essentially, I want the elements in list e1 to be replaced with elements in list e2 and the elements in list e2 to be replaced with list e1.

Comment: Is there a way for me to simply do this?  var temp = e1.sublist, e1.sublist = e2.sublist, e2.sublist = temp.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be easily solved using JQuery **appendTo** method.

```
var childL1 = $('#e1').children();
var childL2 = $('#e2').children();

childL2.appendTo($('#e1'));
childL1.appendTo($('#e2'));
```

Comment: I can't modify the existing html page, I can only modify the functions so using JQuery is out of the question :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 var sublist1 = document.getElementById('e1');
 var sublist2 = document.getElementById('e2');

 document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].childNodes[1].appendChild(sublist2);
 document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].childNodes[3].appendChild(sublist1);
```